# I can't load the css files

Tags: css, django

I want to load some .css files to my Django project but I don't know why they aren't loaded. The css files are located at "/myproject/media/css".

settings.py:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
```

)

base.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}css/myStyle.css" />
```

Comment: So what HTML gets output from the program? Does it give you the final URI that you expect? What happens if you visit the URI that is output?

Comment: Is this using the development server you are trying to get this to work?

Comment: The HTML outputs the page without applying the css styles, like it doesn't exists.

I'm using the development server.

Comment: Don't tell us what the browser does with the HTML. Tell us what the HTML looks like!

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css" />. 
The server outputs this:"GET /alumnos/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2360

And that could be the problem, because "alumnos" is an external app, apart from the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the *file* path to the assets, not the URL. The URL is set in urls.py, and you've got it as `/media/`, so that's what you need to use in the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark but if you have media root set to /myproject/media and then you reference {{ MEDIA_ROOT}}css/mystyle, aren't you missing a slash in there? So you are requesting /myproject/mediacss/myStyle

I feel you on troubleshooting this though. A pain.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you should be using MEDIA_URL in your templates rather than MEDIA_ROOT.